# If there is a way to express an integer as a sum of three non-zero cubes, then there are infinitely many ways

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, exponentiation, integers, perfect-powers

How to prove the following statement:

"If an integer can be expressed as a sum of three non-zero cubes in a way, then it can be expressed as a sum of three non-zero cubes in infinitely many ways."?

I am not asking you to show me the proof, but hopefully one can give me a hint where I can start.

Your help would be really appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: What is the source of this problem? It sounds more like a conjecture.

Comment: Isn't this a part of an open problem? ([Sums of three cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sums_of_three_cubes)) For example, for number $3$, two representations are know, but it is not known if more exist or not.

Answer (score 3):

This a part of an open problem, [Sums of three cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sums_of_three_cubes).

For example, parametric solutions are known for $1$ and $2$, but not for $3$.

For $3$, two representations were known for a long time,

$$
3=1^3+1^3+1^3=4^3+4^3+(-5)^3
$$

And in $2019$, a third representation was found

$$
3=569936821221962380720^{3}+(-569936821113563493509)^{3}+(-472715493453327032)^{3}
$$

But it is not known if there are more or not.